# REGEX to find the first one or two capitalized words in a string

Tags: regex

I am looking for a REGEX to find the first one or two capitalized words in a string. If the first two words is capitalized I want the first two words. A hyphen should be considered part of a word.

1. for `Madonna has a new album` I'm looking for `madonna`
2. for `Paul Young has no new album` I'm looking for `Paul Young`
3. for `Emmerson Lake-palmer is not here` I'm looking for `Emmerson Lake-palmer`

I have been using `^[A-Z]+.*?\b( [A-Z]+.*?\b){0,1}` which does great on the first two, but for the 3rd example I get `Emmerson Lake`, instead of `Emmerson Lake-palmer`.

What REGEX can I use to find the first one or two capitalized words in the above examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
^[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]*)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DiQUic/2)

Basically, use a character class `[-a-zA-Z]*` instead of a dot matching pattern to only match letters and a hyphen.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[-a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters / hyphens
- `(?:\s+[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]*)?` - an optional (1 or 0 due to `?` quantifier) sequence of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespace
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `[-a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters / hyphens

A Unicode aware equivalent (for the regex flavors supporting Unicode property classes):

```
^\p{Lu}[-\p{L}]*(?:\s+\p{Lu}[-\p{L}]*)?
```

where `\p{L}` matches any letter and `\p{Lu}` matches any uppercase letter.

Comment: I have added the pattern explanation and updated the demo link.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. Note that you can also make character classes work the other way by specifying characters to exclude; for example, `[^ ]` would match anything that's not a space.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably simpler:

```
^([A-Z][-A-Za-z]+)(\s[A-Z][-A-Za-z]+)?
```

Replace `+` with `*` if you expect single-letter words.

Comment: This will return ALL capitalised words, not just the first one or two capitalized words in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If u need a **Full name** only (*a two words with the first capitalize letters*), this is a simple example:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*)(\s)([A-Z][a-z]+)$
```

Try it. Enjoy!